# Starting the django development server

Tags: django

i have a problem when i try to start my django development server using manage.py runserver. This is my first time trying to run the server as i am new to django. I get the following error:
Validating models...

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <dja
ngo.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x000000
00033E8278>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 277,
 in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", lin
e 32, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 164, in
 get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 70, in
_populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 94, in
load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 15, i
n <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.hashers import (
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py", line 8, i
n <module>
    from django.test.signals import setting_changed
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\test\__init__.py", line 6, in <modu
le>
    from django.test.testcases import (TestCase, TransactionTestCase,
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 923, in <m
odule>
    _ImprovedEvent = threading._Event
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_Event'
```

please help....

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error message because you are using Python 3.

Django 1.5 will have experimental support for Python 3.x. If you are using an earlier version of Django, then you must use Python 2.x instead.

Comment: [Python 2.7 is the most appropriate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#python-compatibility)

Comment: @goliney it depends on which (if any) python ships with the os, but in this case, where the op is using Windows, I agree that 2.7 is the best choice.

Comment: True am using python 3.3.0. Anywayz thanx a lot :-)